# Code Signing Error: No profiles for app were found. How to solve?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

> Check dependencies Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.app528054'
>   were found:
>   Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning
>   profiles matching 'com.app528054'. 
>   Automatic signing is disabled and
>   unable to generate a profile.
>
> To enable automatic signing, pass
>   -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. 
>   Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.1'

I don't get this error. I can build the app via xCode and I don't get any errors, except for the fact that **I can't see my code changes in the app** (as it's probably not synchronized because of the error above).

When I try `ionic cordova build ios`, though, it gives me this stacktrace.

I have signed the app with my Apple Developer account and thus that shouldn't be the problem.

Where can I match the profile of the app? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 17):

I'm getting this very same error on the `cordova build ios` every time my iPhone is plugged in at that Mac I'm running the command.

The iPhone will appear under Devices and Simulators in Xcode and apparently during the build its checked if u have a valid provisioning profile for that device.

Unplugging the iPhone and the error is gone. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: OMG! This was the culprit!  I have been scratching my head for so long! thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: After hours of searching, this finally worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar code-signing problem that I solved in XCode but could not get to build from a command line.  I found the value in the "build.json" file that I needed to manually change to properly reflect the value I had set in XCode:

```
"debug": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam": "5QAC6D6FT5",
        "packageType": "development",
        "provisioningProfile":"[incorrect provisioning profile]",
        "buildFlag": [
            "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
            "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
            "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
        ]
    }
```

In my case, I had the correct blank (automatic?) setting in XCode but that blank setting was not picked up during a cordova build.  Manually removing it from the build.json allowed the successfully signed build in cordova.